How do I implement a thread-per-request model using Vert.x Web's HTTP server on Vert.x 4.4.1?
I'm trying to implement a thread-per-request design using Vert.x Web's HTTP server. When I run the following code, I am not able to process any more requests until response.end() is called:
final var server = vertx.createHttpServer(serverOptions).requestHandler(req -> {
            // workerPool is a thread pool with 10 threads
            workerPool.execute {
              var response = req.response();
              longRunningTask();
              response.end("Done.")
            }
    })

I confirmed the culprit was response.end() by changing my code to the following:
final var server = vertx.createHttpServer(serverOptions).requestHandler(req -> {
                // workerPool is a thread pool with 10 threads
                var response = req.response();
                workerPool.execute {
                  longRunningTask();
                }
                response.end("Done.")
        })

But this isn't thread-per-request as I'm just offloading longRunningTask() to a background thread, and quickly dealing with requests on the main thread.
I also tried:

Vertx#executeBlocking()
Setting workerPoolSize to 5
Setting eventLoopPoolSize to 5

and I got a similar result.
I'm on Java 17 and I'm using Vert.x Web 4.4.1 where it seems setting virtual threads and setting Vert.x's threading model are not available. Any idea how to work around this?

If you want thread-per-request model, what is the point of using vert.x?

@ntalbs I'm familiar with it, so I chose it for on a project and I realize I'll have to use some synchronous APIs. Rather than wrapping every API call in async code, I figured it might be easier if I could handle each web request in its own thread.

Assuming the workerPool in your code is an instance of ExecutorService. That would be a completely different thread scheduler than Vert.x. Mixing both schedulers (Vert.x, ExecutorService) will almost certainly lead you into catching concurrency bugs.
For the same reason and because it would be wasteful, you should not try to build a thread-per-request server on top of Vert.x.
If it's only about avoiding Vert.x' Future... your options on JVM 17 are using Kotlin with Coroutines or one of the reactive libraries like RxJava or Mutiny. However, these will also not turn async code magically into sync code. Imho, Vert.x Future is a nice abstraction of what is actually going on. I'll stick with it.
Let's look at how to get your longRunningTask() to work in a Vert.x application. There are three ways to make Vert.x return an HTTP response after longRunningTask() has finished:
Option 1: vertx.executeBlocking()
You can offload any Callable to Vert.x' worker thread pool:
httpServer.requestHandler(req ->
    vertx
        .executeBlocking(() -> longRunningTask()) // Future<Void>
        .onSuccess(__ -> req.response().end("Done."))
);

Option 2: Use a shared WorkerExecutor
You can create a separate shared worker pool that is compatible with Vert.x. The name that you assign to it identifies the worker pool in your application, so you can grab it by that name from other places as well:
httpServer.requestHandler(req ->
    vertx
        .createSharedWorkerExecutor("slow-tasks", 10) // 10 threads
        .executeBlocking(() -> longRunningTask())     // Future<Void>
        .onSuccess(__ -> req.response().end("Done."))
);

Option 3: Use a Worker Verticle
Worker Verticles can make sense when you want to share a blocking operation between all Verticles or even in a cluster. They are programmed just like normal Verticles. However, they are deployed with DeploymentOptions().setWorker(true).
Worker Verticle
This could be your Worker Verticle:
public final class LongRunningTaskVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Promise<Void> startPromise) {
        vertx
            .eventBus()
            .consumer("org.me.longrunning") // event bus address
            .handler(msg -> {
                longRunningTask();
                msg.reply("ok");
            });
    }
}

Call it from an HTTP request handler
Calling the Worker Verticle from an HTTP request handler is like:
httpServer.requestHandler(req ->
    vertx
        .eventBus()
        .<String> request("org.me.longrunning", "")   // Future<Message<String>>
        .onSuccess(__ -> req.response().end("Done."))
);


I tried Option 1, but it appears to give the same result as the second code snippet in my question. I think I'll just have to be as efficient as possible with my synchronous code and offload things to worker threads where I can. Thank you for your answer.

Each of the 3 implementations send a response onSuccess. So, if you say responses are sent before the computation in longRunningTask() is finished, I would conclude that the method longRunningTask() is itself async or is not properly chaining async tasks?

Yes, they will send the response when the task is finished, but the problem is I can't receive any more requests until a response is sent. Notice that in my first example, I'm attempting to process the request, do a long running task and send a response all in one thread. Even this approach doesn't allow me to handle new requests in another thread.

Your first example clearly blocks the event loop since longRunningTask() is done in an event loop thread. Vert.x should emit a warning that the event loop is blocked for n seconds... In contrast, if you use executeBlocking() or worker Verticles, like shown above, then the event loop and thus further requests should not be blocked. Vert.x should not emit a warning in that case. The single one request you made initially will be blocked however. But that's what is intended, isn't it? At this point it might be more helpful if you created a reproducer for a better analysis of the problem...

I think I understand. I forgot that you mentioned Vert.x uses a different thread scheduler than the one Java provides. I'll rework my code to use the Vert.x scheduler exclusively. Thank you!
